# Como hago para que entity framwork (code first) visualice unos store procedure ya creados

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, stored-procedure

He creado varios store procedures directamente en la base de datos , al momento de querer utilizarlos y visualizarlos con entity framework **(dbcontext)** no se visualizan , basicamente no puedo acceder a los store procedures.

**mi aproach es CODE FIRST con entity framework**.

Comment: Esto te puede ayudar: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/299/entity-framework-code-first-and-stored-procedures + lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Muchas gracias, excelente aporte